# WPF OxyPlot: How to give option to the user which series to display?

Tags: wpf, oxyplot

I would like to present to the user list of available series to choose from (maybe directly by clicking the legend?)
The plot would display only the chosen series

What would be the best way to achieve this ?

Comment: Apparently it's something that is considered by the Oxyplot team but not implemented yet: https://github.com/oxyplot/oxyplot/issues/315

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you to use checkboxes which represent those series. When a user checks a checkbox, you can add a new LineSeries or any other series to the PlotModel/PlotView.

checkbox1 represents series1.
checkbox2 represents series2.
etc..

ex:

```
Plotview pv = new PlotView(); // you can also use plotmodel instead of plotview.
  pv.Width = 480.0;
  pv.Height = 272.0;
  pv.Title = graphname;
private void checkbox4_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  var LineChart = new LineSeries();

        pv.Series.Add(LineChart);

        LineChart.DataFieldX = "X";
        LineChart.DataFieldY = "Y";

        List<Vector> coords = new List<Vector>(); 
        //Add X and Y values to this list. Or you can use any other way you want.

        LineChart.ItemsSource = coords; //Feed it to itemsource
        LineChart.Title = name;
}
```

Comment: Yes. That was what I eventually did

Answer (score 0):

Here's my MVVM solution found with a colleague to allow user to choose series to display :

Firstable we create a PlotView in xaml with an ItemsControl binded on PlotModel.Series :

```
<oxy:PlotView Background="Transparent" Model="{Binding PlotModelCompareChart}" x:Name="CompareChart"/>
        <Border Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,150,0,0" BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="1" Height="80">
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding PlotModelCompareChart.Series}" Margin="5" >
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True">
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type oxy:Series}">

                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <CheckBox IsChecked="True" Tag="{Binding ElementName=CompareChart}"  >
                                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Checked">
                                        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ElementName=userControl, Path=DataContext.ManageCheckBoxCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=CheckBox}}" ></i:InvokeCommandAction>
                                    </i:EventTrigger>
                                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Unchecked">
                                        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ElementName=userControl, Path=DataContext.ManageCheckBoxCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=CheckBox}}"></i:InvokeCommandAction>
                                    </i:EventTrigger>

                                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                            </CheckBox>
                            <Rectangle Width="15" Height="3.5"  Margin="5,0,0,0" Fill="{Binding Color, Converter={StaticResource OxyColorToSolidColorBrushConverter}}"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Margin="5,0,0,0" ></TextBlock>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </Border>
```

The converter to convert the OxyColor received to fill the rectangle (You have to set the color of your Series, if you let Oxyplot choose the color, it doesn't work) :

```
public class OxyColorToSolidColorBrushConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (null == value)
        {
            return null;
        }

        if (value is OxyColor)
        {
            var color = (SolidColorBrush)new BrushConverter().ConvertFrom(value.ToString());
            return color;
        }

        Type type = value.GetType();
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Unsupported type [" + type.Name + "]");
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Now the code in the ViewModel :

--PlotModel Creation --

```
 public PlotModel PlotModelCompareChart => CreatePlotModelForCompareChart(DataPoints);
 public PlotModel CreatePlotModelForCompareChart(StripLengthReferentialDataPointCollection points)
    {
        var plotModel= new PlotModel();
        plotModel.IsLegendVisible = false;
        var linearAxis = new LinearAxis
        {
            Position = AxisPosition.Bottom,
            MajorGridlineStyle = LineStyle.Solid,
            Title = LabelsAndMessagesRes.StripLengthReferentialChart_Legend_HeadPosition,
            Unit = PhysicalQuantityManager.Instance.LengthAcronym
        };
        var linearAxis2 = new LinearAxis
        {
            Position = AxisPosition.Left,
            Title = LabelsAndMessagesRes.Lexicon_Temperature,
            Unit = PhysicalQuantityManager.Instance.TemperatureAcronym
        };

        var linearAxis3 = new LinearAxis
        {
            Position = AxisPosition.Right,
            Maximum = 70,
            Key = "ValveAxis"
        };


        plotModel.Axes.Add(linearAxis);
        plotModel.Axes.Add(linearAxis2);
        plotModel.Axes.Add(linearAxis3);


        var lineSeries = new LineSeries();
        lineSeries.Title = LabelsAndMessagesRes.StripLengthReferentialChart_Legend_MeasuredCoilingTemperature;
        lineSeries.DataFieldX = "HeadPosition";
        lineSeries.DataFieldY = "MeasuredCoilingTemperature";
        lineSeries.ItemsSource = points;
        lineSeries.Color = OxyColors.Green;

        var lineSeries2 = new LineSeries();
        lineSeries2.Title = "All valves count";
        lineSeries2.DataFieldX = "HeadPosition";
        lineSeries2.DataFieldY = "AllValvesCount";
        lineSeries2.YAxisKey = "ValveAxis";
        lineSeries2.ItemsSource = points;
        lineSeries2.Color = OxyColors.LightSeaGreen;

        plotModel.Series.Add(lineSeries);
        plotModel.Series.Add(lineSeries2);


        return plotModel;

    }
```

-- The Command and Method for Checkbox events (Unchecked and Checked)

```
  public ICommand ManageCheckBoxCommand { get; private set; }
```

In Ctor :

```
 ManageCheckBoxCommand = new GalaSoft.MvvmLight.CommandWpf.RelayCommand<object>(ManageCheckBoxMethod);
```

The Method :

```
 private void ManageCheckBoxMethod(object obj)
    {
        if(obj != null)
        {
            var checkbox = obj as CheckBox;
            var datacontext = checkbox.DataContext as Series;
            datacontext.IsVisible = checkbox.IsChecked.Value;
            var plotView = checkbox.Tag as OxyPlot.Wpf.PlotView;
            plotView.Model = null;
            plotView.Model = datacontext.PlotModel;
        }

    }
```

And now the result :
[Options checked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UB7yD.png)

[Options not checked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8xig.png)

Hope it helps !

Answer (score 0):

An update to Lucas's answer found above. I assume OxyPlot has changed or broken interface in two ways since last year: 1) because the binding of Color fails now, so I bound against the property ActualColor and this worked.  2) However, with plots with lots of "Series" (such as LineSeries) OxyPlot does its assignment of 12 different solid colors, then the next 12 are dashed colors, then the next 12 are dotted line colors to the overall collection of "Series" so you need to work with ActualLineStyle, but OxyPlot unfortunately marked it "protected".   So XAML adjustment replaces the rectangle in Lucas's answer:

```
<Line Stroke="{Binding ActualColor, Converter={StaticResource OxyColorToSolidColorBrushConverter}}"
StrokeThickness="3" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" 
StrokeDashArray="{Binding MyActualLineStyle, Converter={StaticResource LineStyleToDashArrayConverter}}"
Height="3" Width="30" X1="0" Y1="0" X2="30" Y2="0"/>
```

And the new converter is:

```
public class LineStyleToDashArrayConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            return null;
        } 

        double[] array = LineStyleHelper.GetDashArray((LineStyle)value);
        return array == null ? null : new DoubleCollection(array); // switches double array to double collection
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And the new child class of OxyPlot's LineSeries that will expose the ActualLineStyle property (assuming your series are lines):

```
public class MyLineSeries : LineSeries
{
    public LineStyle MyActualLineStyle => ActualLineStyle; 
}
```

And thus you create instances of this new LineSeries child class, instead of LineSeries:

```
 MyLineSeries ls = new MyLineSeries() { Title = sq };
 ls.Points.AddRange(_points); // a line consisting of multiple points
 MyPlotModel.Series.Add(ls); // a line for each onto the overall plot model
```